# JQuery Code works in chrome and IE but it not works in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I can't find the problem
please help me
my jquery code works in IE and Chrome but it doesn't work in firefox
my code snippet is:

```
var dto = { 'searchObj': LogInObj };
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "Default.aspx/GetLogIn",
        //url: "Services.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: JSON.stringify(dto),
        //data:'{}',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (result) {
            var rt = result.d;
            if (rt.Success) {
                var data = rt.Data;
                $.session.set('UserId', data[0].UserId);
                var userType = data[0].UserTypeId;
                if (userType == 1) {
                    LogInPage.GetClientInfo(data[0].UserId);
                    **LogInPage.SaveUserLogs();**
                    window.location = 'AdminManager.aspx';
                }
                else if (userType == 2) {
                    LogInPage.GetClientInfo(data[0].UserId);
                    LogInPage.SaveUserLogs();
                    window.location = 'Base.aspx';
                    }
                else
                    alert('
```

I need to call LogInPage.SaveUserLogs() method.
thanks for response

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? It wouldn't hurt to mention what the code is supposed to do, and what happens when you run it in Firefox... (By the way, you know Javascript is case sensitive, right? `datatype: "Json"` should be `dataType: "json"`.)

Comment: Buddy, First of all your questions is too short in terms of what you are asking. You We need to know which part is not working, How are you calling it and what data you are using . Please add a jsfiddle or a code snippet here so that we can Help. Also simplify your code. It's not possible that all of your code will not work. Only a part may not be working and you need to  point out that part to us

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use keyup event for text input that it doesn't work in firefox
so i change it to keypress and my problem be solved.
I can give more details if necessary.